# solve Equation a+b+c+d=a*b*c*d

Tags: algorithm, math

Hello i am trying to solve this equation for a programming problem that states that you need to do a complete search algorithm to find this results.

However an O(N^4) algorithm takes a lot of time, since the range for each value of A,B,C, and D, is (0,2000] . so we can say A<=B<=C<=D

i want to make my algorithm faster translating it to a O(n^3) solution. For doing that i am taking into account certain things with A,B and C to make the algorithm runs a little faster (prunning). But the main issue is to take out the search of D, i have read some solutions for a similar problem and the way they find D derivating it from A+B+C=A*B*C is really confusing, can somebody explain to me the O(N^3) solution to this problem? thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that article is terrible, long-winded and condescending.

Comment: @djechlin: Then you should comment in that article, or respond to it, but are you saying I don't have a point? He's asking for us to do his work for him. Instead, he should try first.

Comment: @JohnSaunders did you actually read the question, by the way?

Comment: @djechlin: did he show what he tried, and I just didn't notice?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes. 1) pruning, 2) realizes you must eliminate the D term, 3) researched similar solutions trying to derive from the 3 variable problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalently d = (a+b+c)/(abc-1). Now just walk over all values of a, b, and c, seeing which ones return an integer value for d.

Furthermore a+b+c < abc-1 when a,b,c >= 2. Should shorten your search time quite a bit...

Comment: Will that ever happen when `a > 1`?

Comment: @Rhymoid I don't know, but I know how to find out in O(n^3) time.

Comment: @Rhymoid looks like no, since, as I was last to notice, abcd is usually bigger than a+b+c+d.

Comment: Something similar goes for `b > 1`, by the way. You end up with `A=B=1`, `(2+C)=(C-1)D`. It should be evident that, except for small values of `C`, `C-1` doesn't divide `2+C`. In conclusion: there's probably only one solution.

Answer (score 5):

The equation

```
A * B * C * D == A + B + C + D
```

has just one solution

```
1 1 2 4
```

So time complexity is `O(1)`.

---

Since `A <= B <= C <= D`,

```
A + B + C + D <= 4 * D
```

hence

```
A * B * C * D <= 4 * D
```

and

```
A * B * C <= 4
```

Therefore, it is enough to check just a few combinations:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 4; a++)
    for(int b = a; b <= 4; b++)
        for(int c = b; c <= 4; c++)
        {
            // a*b*c*d == a+b+c+d
            // => d == (a+b+c) / (a*b*c - 1)
            if(a * b * c - 1 != 0 && (a + b + c) % (a * b * c - 1) == 0)
            {
                int d = (a + b + c) / (a * b * c - 1);
                if (d >= c)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
                        a, b, c, (a + b + c) / (a * b * c - 1));
            }
        }
```

Comment: this would only answer the question if you can answer your own question.

Comment: Okay, so add that to your answer.

Comment: +1, mostly just to cancel the other -1 you had hanging out.

Comment: "Does the equation [have] any solution besides `1 1 2 4`?" No, that is the unique solution.

Comment: For a sequence S = {s_1, s_2, .., s_n}, we want to solve: s_1 + s_2 + .. + s_n = s_1 x s_2 x .. s_n

Where n >= 3, we set: s_1 = 1, .., s_(n-2) = 1, s_(n-1) = 2, s_(n) = n

Examples:

n = 3, S = {1, 2, 3} (1+2+3 = 1x2x3 = 6)

n = 4, S = {1, 1, 2, 4} (1+1+2+4 = 1x1x2x4 = 8)

n = 5, S = {1, 1, 1, 2, 5} (1+1+1+2+5 = 1x1x1x2x5 = 10)

n = 6, S = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6} (1+1+1+1+2+6 = 1x1x1x1x2x6 = 12)